# Get fullpath from paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have paperclip, but its url method returns only the path not the full url. I want to construct the full url from that paperclip. Beside doing string concatenation, is there a better way to create full url from a image path string like "/images/11/1.jpg"?

E.g. Given the string "/images/11/1.jpg", I want to get "http://www.example.com/images/11/1.jpg"

Additionally, I want to switch the subdomain to 'assets'.

Comment: Try with @object.image_field.url

Comment: It returns path, not the full url

Comment: Do you want fullpath (/home/xyz/your-application-name/public/images/11/1.jpg) or the full url (http://your-domain/images/11/1.jpg)?

Comment: Try this in your controller or views `URI.join(request.url, file.url(style))` where file is the returned image object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use environment variables in paperclip...

[Using the Rails Enviroment URL in a MODEL with paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231335/using-the-rails-enviroment-url-in-a-model-with-paperclip)

but i don't know if it still works